# Attempting to use EF/Linq to Entities for dynamic querying and CRUD operations

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

(as advised re-posting this question here... originally posted in msdn forum)

I am striving to write a "generic" routine for some simple CRUD operations using EF/Linq to Entities.  I'm working in ASP.NET (C# or VB).

I have looked at:

1. Getting a reference to a dynamically selected table with "GetObjectByKey" (But I don't want anything from cache. I want data from database. Seems like not what this function is intended for).
2. CRM Dynamic Entities (here you can pass a tablename string to query) looked like the approach I am looking for but I don't get the idea that this CRM effort is necessarily staying current (?) and/or has much assurance for the future??
3. I looked at various ways of drilling thru Namespaces/Objects to get to where I could pass a TableName parameter into the oft used query syntax   var query = (from c in context.C_Contacts select c);  (for example)  where somehow I could swap out the "C_Contacts" TEntity depending on which table I want to work with.  But not finding a way to do this ??

Slightly over-simplyfing, I just want to be able to pass a tablename parameter and in some cases some associated fieldnames and values (perhaps in a generic object?) to my routine and then let that routine dynamically plug into LINQ to Entity data context/model and do some standard "select all" operations for parameter table or do a delete to parameter table based on a generic record id. I'm trying to avoid calling the various different automatically generated L2E methods based on tablename etc...instead just trying to drill into the data context and ultimately the L2E query syntax for  dynamically passed table/field names.

Has anyone found any successful/efficient approaches for doing this? Any ideas, links, examples?

Answer (score 0):

The DbContext object has a generic Set() method. This will give you

```
from c in context.Set<Contact>() select c
```

Here's method when starting from a string:

```
public void Test()
{
    dynamic entity = null;
    Type type = Type.GetType("Contract");
    entity = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    ProcessType(entity);
}

public void ProcessType<TEntity>(TEntity instance)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var result = 
        from item in this.Set<TEntity>()
        select item;

    //do stuff with the result
    //passing back to the caller can get more complicated
    //but passing it on will be fine ...
}
```

Comment: I will explore that. I am using earlier version of EF. That looks like a 5.0 method so I will upgrade.  At present what I now have working is using  context.ExecuteStoreCommand("Delete From _Contacts where ContactID = " + vID)  which actually works.. but doesn't feel like I'm getting full benefit of the many features of EF and L2E !!   ;)  thank you...

Comment: I agree executing sql seems to go against the nature of ORM. If you're upgrading it may be worth going straight to version 6.

Comment: I only use the Set() method. My contexts don't have named DbSets.